# Rich text to be stored using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

If csv file has rich text in it. Using csv.reader() can the same format stored in the Mysql database using django and retrieved back to html pages?

Thanks..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'rich text'? Are you talking about HTML tags, or a particular encoding?

Comment: If a text is added with a different color and font family in the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text or data has no color or creed.

If you have data as text, just store it in text field, if it is binary store it as a blob. It doesn't matter what that data represents, it can be richtext, pdf, a flash file etc database doesn't care.